# Recoll fails to index python files with py filename suffix

Tags: recoll

I use recoll 1.26.3 (french version) xapian 1.4.14  with  mint 20.04

My `recoll` doesn't index files with `py` as filename suffix.

- I have no "missing helper"
- I have no problem indexing `.odt`, `.rpg`, `.pdf`, `.txt` and similar filetypes.

In "index mime type" I find "text/x-python" but no way

Comment: I have the same version of Recoll and the same problem. Try a search by File name with `.py`. Do you have this message : `ERROR: module 'cgi' has no attribute 'escape'…` ?

Comment: Hello gounou,           No, I haven't  any error message. The file i am looking for, is totally ignored.          A  search by file name  finds the file BUT i want to search file containing some string.     If  i specify "ext:py"  recoll finds  files as "my_script.py". BUT i want  to search for a string inside the file!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:
I have upgraded to recoll 1.31.0 and rebuilt the index.